# checkinstall creates useless deb?

Tags: makefile, deb, checkinstall

I have a trivially simple command-line program that literally consists of a python script and some helper shell scripts. I'd like to learn about packaging this program, though it is trivial.

From what I gathered, I went the configure/make/install route. Since I didn't have anything to configure, or anything to make, I simple created a Makefile with nothing but an install section:

```
install:
        cp ./myProgram /usr/bin/my-program
        chown root:root /usr/bin/my-program
        chmod 777 /usr/bin/my-program
        cp -r ./ProgramResources /usr/lib/my-program
        chown -hR root:root /usr/lib/my-program
        chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/my-program
```

At this point, my program installs and runs fine with sudo make install.

Then, I attempt to make a deb file using [checkinstall](http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) as follows:

```
sudo checkinstall sudo make install
```

It appears to get past the install part, as it reports it successful, but then fails:

```
======================== Installation successful ==========================
cp: cannot stat `//var/tmp/tmp.jKCmESc0v7/newfiles.tmp': No such file or directory

Copying files to the temporary directory...OK

Stripping ELF binaries and libraries...OK

Compressing man pages...OK

Building file list... FAILED!

Building Debian package...OK

Installing Debian package...OK

Erasing temporary files...OK

Deleting temp dir...OK


**********************************************************************

 Done. The new package has been installed and saved to

 ...
```

The program is installed, but as far as I can tell, this newly made .deb file does nothing. dpkg -L my-program yields only

```
/.
```

and manually removing it and installing from the deb file doesn't appear to do anything - it doesn't actually put any files anywhere.

So, (1) Is there anything wrong with my approach?
and (2) How can I fix the checkinstall problem?

Thank you very much for answers, even though I'm good with code, I've never known anything about packaging/distribution.

Answer (score 8):

The double use of sudo is the problem.

With a file install.sh like

```
#! /bin/bash
set -x
touch useless
cp useless /usr/share/useless
```

command

```
sudo checkinstall --pkgname useless -y ./install.sh
```

works while

```
sudo checkinstall --pkgname useless -y sudo ./install.sh
                                       ^^^^
```

shows

```
cp: cannot stat ‘//var/tmp/tmp.Au4ympTNlT/newfiles.tmp’: No such file or directory
```

and produces an empty package.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this exactly answers the question, but here's what I got so far (on ubuntu lucid, checkinstall 1.6.1):

I tried to build an open-source project, which built just fine. Then I tried packaging it for debian:

`checkinstall -D --install=no --pkgname=$PKGNAME --pkgversion=0.0.1 --pkgrelease="svn-001" --maintainer=test@test.com --strip=no --stripso=no --addso=yes`

This basically failed at the same `Building file list... FAILED!`; and a similar `grep: /var/tmp/tmp.NaoiwTHT6F/newfile: No such file or directory` was reported.

I also tried with adding `make` at end of `checkinstall` command above - that didn't do much either.

Finally, I tried this:

`make clean

checkinstall -D --install=no --pkgname=$PKGNAME --pkgversion=0.0.1 --pkgrelease="svn-001" --maintainer=test@test.com --strip=no --stripso=no --addso=yes -d2 make`

The switch `-d2` is to enable debug; and `... make` will rerun make one more time.

The `-d2` will print out the temporary directory:

```
debug: The temporary directory is: [ /var/tmp/tmp.NaoiwTHT6F ]
```

, so it can be checked by listing... And indeed, I can confirm that a `newfile` is not generated there in my case (however, there is `newfiles`, `newfiles.installwatch`, `newfiles-tar`, and `newfiles.tmp`). In fact, turns out `checkinstall` is a `bash` script, and so one can confirm that `newfile` only appears once in it:

```
$ grep 'newfile ' `which checkinstall`
    grep '^/home' ${TMP_DIR}/newfile > /${TMP_DIR}/unwanted
```

Also, the debug will point out these files/directories:

```
debug: INSTW_EXCLUDE=/dev,/path/to/myproject-build,/proc,/tmp,/var/tmp,
debug: INSTW_ROOTPATH=/var/tmp/tmp.NaoiwTHT6F
debug: INSTW_LOGFILE=/var/tmp/tmp.NaoiwTHT6F/newfiles.tmp
debug: INSTW_DBGFILE=/var/tmp/tmp.NaoiwTHT6F/dbgfile
```

Note that by default, the path to my build folder, `/path/to/myproject-build` is excluded - and that is where this project also stores the built executables!

Apparently, when `make` within `checkinstall` goes on building for the first time, it can capture newly generated executable files - they will be listed in `${TMP_DIR}/newfiles`; however, in my case, the problem is that the executables end up under the same directory where `checkinstall` is called; thus, at this dialog:

```
Some of the files created by the installation are inside the build
directory: /path/to/myproject-build

You probably don't want them to be included in the package,
especially if they are inside your home directory.
Do you want me to list them?  [n]: y
Should I exclude them from the package? (Saying yes is a good idea)  [y]: n
```

... I *must*, in fact, answer `n` - otherwise I'd get nothing included! I can then check the contents with:

```
dpkg --contents mytest.deb | less
```

However, then the problem is that `checkinstall`:

- *also* includes `.o` files, as well as `.svn` directories
- counts the absolute path as relative (will not automatically "send" executables to say, `/usr/bin`, and `.so`s to `/usr/lib`

In brief - some of the approaches above may get one to have a `.deb` which is not completely empty; but that doesn't mean one has only the needed files there, or that they would be routed to usual install destinations...

Well, hope this helps at least a bit,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems. In the end i followed [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/) very simple, but fairly manual approach.

Place the files you want to package in debian/usr/bin for example. There's no need to complete the usual `configure, make, make install` steps.

Comment: No idea, how to get there! Have Java app as jar file and some install script. Think all these perscriptions don't cover my case.